# What does 'nan' mean in lidar's scan data?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm working with the ROS kinetic of Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm also using Hokuyo's lidar sensor and recently realized that there are some strange data in the returned data of `/scan` topic.

The `nan` data, which stands for 'not a number', is that; if so, what is the 'nan'?

Although I've worked with a lidar sensor for over 2 years, I have no idea about when the `nan` data is created.

What's the `nan` in this? It doesn't matter when it comes to the `g-mapping` or other packages, but I need to do another work whit this data and `nan` makes no sense.

If someone familiar with lidar's range data is here, would you please give me some help?

The below is the `/scan` data including `nan`.

```
header: 
  seq: 6147
  stamp: 
    secs: 1627028918
    nsecs: 664962817
  frame_id: "base_footprint"
angle_min: -2.07394194603
angle_max: 2.07394218445
angle_increment: 0.00613592332229
time_increment: 2.71259814326e-05
scan_time: 0.0277769993991
range_min: 0.019999999553
range_max: 5.59999990463
ranges: [nan, nan, 2.802000045776367, 2.7309999465942383, 2.7090001106262207, 2.677000045776367,...]
```

Thanks :)

---

(add)

According to [this page](https://answers.ros.org/question/200667/changing-value-0nan-to-max-distance-urghokuyo-node/), I think the `nan` data might mean the max_range value. Is it right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383055/what-does-%27nan%27-mean-in-lidar%27s-scan-data?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2021-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ktysai](https://answers.ros.org/users/41908/ktysai/) on 2021-07-23**:
It's corect! There is no obstacle at the maximum reading range.
BTW, you've tested this lidar only indoor?

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2021-07-23**:
@Ktysai Thanks for the kind comment. Yeah, I've never used it on the road..

**Comment by [Lennart](https://answers.ros.org/users/52806/lennart/) on 2021-07-25**:
Your linked questions (or the best answer to that) speaks from two modes ( urg_node or the hokuyo_node). Which mode are you using? Which error code do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the driver follows [REP-117](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0117.html), NAN means "erroneous, invalid or missing measurement". While not every ROS driver follows REP-117, most do.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2021-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2021-07-25**:
Yeah, you're right. I just modified those `nan` data to be the max_range value, and it worked. Although all the `nan` doesn't mean out of range, it would be up to the user :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, `nan` has no standard interpretation beyond "ray value is not in supported range". In general, you can't interpret it as "greater than range_max", although with testing you might decide that is true for your specific lidar. What I do is ignore a ray with this value.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems not to be a ROS specific question but a LIDAR specific question. nan means mostly the LIDAR didn't received the his laser-ray.  The most reasonable answer is "out of range". It could also have other reasons like bright light as noise or "bad" surfaces that don't reflect the ray back to the LIDAR.
At your place I would search the answer to your question in first point by the LIDAR. I guess it's a measuring issue.

---

Originally posted by [Lennart](https://answers.ros.org/users/52806/lennart/) with karma: 40 on 2021-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2021-07-25**:
Thanks for the answer. I'm using [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node), so I couldn't sure whether the `nan` really comes from 'out of range'. I still can't say all the `nan` should mean that clearly, it seems I need to check the test room concerning a surface or reflected light more carefully.

For the error message, I didn't get any messages but only the bugs without them, which is one of the most annoying situations :)